# Create multiple list items using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have tried to create multiple list items in sharepoint  online using rest, I am getting the success message but still the items are not created in the list.

Below is the code:-

```
function CreateIdea(){
      var EmployeesAsJson = [
            {
                __metadata: {
                    type: 'SP.Data.IdeaEngineListItem'
                },
                Title: 'User1'
            },
            {
                __metadata: {
                    type: 'SP.Data.IdeaEngineListItem'
                },
                Title: 'User2'
            },
            {
                 __metadata: {
                     type: 'SP.Data.IdeaEngineListItem'
                 },
                 Title: 'User3'
             }
      ];             


// generate a batch boundary
        var batchGuid = generateUUID();

        // creating the body
        var batchContents = new Array();
        var changeSetId = generateUUID();

        // get current host
        var temp = document.createElement('a');
        temp.href = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
        var host = temp.hostname;

        // for each employee...
        for (var employeeIndex = 0; employeeIndex < EmployeesAsJson.length; employeeIndex++) {

            var employee = EmployeesAsJson[employeeIndex];

            // create the request endpoint
            var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
                           + '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'IdeaEngine\')'
                           + '/items';

            // create the changeset
            batchContents.push('--changeset_' + changeSetId);
            batchContents.push('Content-Type: application/http');
            batchContents.push('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            batchContents.push('');
            batchContents.push('POST ' + endpoint + ' HTTP/1.1');
            batchContents.push('Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose');
            batchContents.push('');
            batchContents.push(JSON.stringify(employee));
            batchContents.push('');
        }
        // END changeset to create data
        batchContents.push('--changeset_' + changeSetId + '--');

        // generate the body of the batch
        var batchBody = batchContents.join('\r\n');

        // create the request endpoint 
        var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
                       + '/_api/$batch';

        // batches need a specific header
        var batchRequestHeader = {
            'X-RequestDigest': jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_' + batchGuid + '"'
        };

        // create request
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: endpoint,
            type: 'POST',
            headers: batchRequestHeader,
            data: batchBody,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Successfully saved a batch request");
                SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel);
            },
            fail: function (error) {
                alert('.. create employee FAIL ', error);
                SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel);
            }
        });
}

/*
    * @name generateUUID
    * @description
    * Generates a GUID-like string, used in OData HTTP batches.
    * 
    * @returns {string} - A GUID-like string.
    */
function generateUUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d / 16);
        return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x7 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
};
```

Please help me know where is the issue in the code. I have referred the post [https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/878531/Save-Mutiple-records-to-SharePoint-using-REST-API]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to specify start and end of batch in body

```
--batch_someguid
body
--batch_someguid--
```

Secondly,
*a changeset must start with the batch boundary and include some specific lines describing the actual changeset.*
For e.g. as below

```
--batch_someguid
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="changeset_guid"
Host: [your-sponline-domain]
Content-Length: [size in bytes of the changeset]
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

You can follow [this](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/part-2-sharepoint-rest-api-batching-exploring-batch-requests-responses-and-changesets) post from Andrew Connell to understand batch request properly

Modified code is as below

```
function CreateIdea(){
  var EmployeesAsJson = [
        {
            __metadata: {
                type: 'SP.Data.IdeaEngineListItem'
            },
            Title: 'User1'
        },
        {
            __metadata: {
                type: 'SP.Data.IdeaEngineListItem'
            },
            Title: 'User2'
        },
        {
             __metadata: {
                 type: 'SP.Data.IdeaEngineListItem'
             },
             Title: 'User3'
         }
  ];             


    // generate a batch boundary
    var batchGuid = generateUUID();

    // creating the body
    var batchContents = new Array();
    var changeSetId = generateUUID();

    // get current host
    var temp = document.createElement('a');
    temp.href = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var host = temp.hostname;

    batchContents.push('--batch_' + batchGuid);
    batchContents.push('Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="changeset_' + changeSetId + '"');
    batchContents.push('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    batchContents.push(''); //NECESSARY LINE SPACE

    // for each employee...
    for (var employeeIndex = 0; employeeIndex < EmployeesAsJson.length; employeeIndex++) {

        var employee = EmployeesAsJson[employeeIndex];

        // create the request endpoint
        var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
                       + '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'IdeaEngine\')'
                       + '/items';

        // create the changeset
        batchContents.push('--changeset_' + changeSetId);
        batchContents.push('Content-Type: application/http');
        batchContents.push('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        batchContents.push('');
        batchContents.push('POST ' + endpoint + ' HTTP/1.1');
        batchContents.push('Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose');
        batchContents.push('');
        batchContents.push(JSON.stringify(employee));
        batchContents.push('');
    }
    // END changeset to create data
    batchContents.push('--changeset_' + changeSetId + '--');
    batchContents.push('--batch_' + batchGuid + '--');  //END OF BATCH

    // generate the body of the batch
    var batchBody = batchContents.join('\r\n');

    // create the request endpoint 
    var endpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
                   + '/_api/$batch';

    // batches need a specific header
    var batchRequestHeader = {
        'X-RequestDigest': jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_' + batchGuid + '"'
    };

    // create request
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: endpoint,
        type: 'POST',
        headers: batchRequestHeader,
        data: batchBody,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Successfully saved a batch request");
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel);
        },
        fail: function (error) {
            alert('.. create employee FAIL ', error);
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel);
        }
    });
  }

  function generateUUID() {
   var d = new Date().getTime();
   var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
    var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    d = Math.floor(d / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x7 | 0x8)).toString(16);
 });
  return uuid;
 };
```

Comment: How can we get the list items from multiple lists using batch REST API?